# Removing object (inside ROI) from frame by frame then combine back to a video in opencv c++

Tags: c++, opencv, video

I have a project which need to insert something into video or removing item(e.g. cars) from the video. My concept was as follow:

1. Read the video frame by frame,
2. found the ROI want to do something on it, 
   for example in my code I try to crop the car(static) out,
3. Remove whatever inside the ROI
4. Recover the background by using (bilinear interpolation?)
5. Output the interpolated video.

Can anyone show me the example code or some reference for this?

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <cv.h>
    #include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp"
    #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

    using namespace cv;
    using namespace std;

    CvCapture* cap = NULL;
    Mat frame;
    Mat edges;
    BackgroundSubtractorMOG2 bg;

    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {

        cap = cvCreateFileCapture("inputfilehere");
        if(!cap)
            return -1;

        bg.set("nmixtures", 6);
        bg.set("detectShadows",false);

        //namedWindow("edges",CV_WINDOW_FREERATIO);
        //namedWindow("result",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);

        while(1){
            frame = cvQueryFrame(cap);
            Mat img;
            img = frame;
            cvtColor(frame, edges, CV_BGR2GRAY);
            Mat roi = img(Rect(130,300,70,40)); // the car location from my video or whatever object
            GaussianBlur(edges, edges, Size(7,7), 1.5, 1.5);
            Canny(edges, edges, 0, 30, 3);
            imshow("Input Video", frame);
            imshow("ROI",roi);
            printf("Value: %d\n", static_cast<int>(frame.at<uchar>(0,0)));

            //system("PAUSE");

            if(waitKey(30) >= 0) break;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: please use cv::VideoCapture instead of the deprecated CvCapture*

Answer (score -1):

I've ever doing this topic.

I suppose the screen is stable.
I think you can follow these steps:

1. Create a background. Use HSV color space.
2. subtract image between your "destination frame"(any include object frame) and background.
3. After step 2 you'll get a different image, and set a threshold at channel H and V to binary image.
4. Remove noise by contour area size.
5. Smooth binary image use Gaussblur (maybe filter size 15*15). you'll get a more complete object image.
6. Make object image as mask you can delete the object and recover use background image.

Good luck!